# Expand each line of text file according to their corresponding numbers on linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, bioinformatics

Can I transfer this first format to the second one just by basic shell procession or awk or sed on linux?

This is a toy example:

This kind of text file is what I have, three cols, col2 and col3 like range, left close and right open,

```
chr1 0 2 0  
chr1 2 6 1.5  
chr2 0 3 0  
chr2 3 10 2.1
```

Transfer to describe each position as:

```
chr1 0 0  
chr1 1 0  
chr1 2 1.5  
chr1 3 1.5  
chr1 4 1.5  
chr1 5 1.5  
chr2 0 0      
chr2 1 0  
chr2 2 0    
chr2 3 2.1  
...  
chr2 9 2.1
```

Comment: https://www.biostars.org/p/325861/

Comment: Sorry, I wait a quite long time, and thought I wouldn't get answer here anymore. But I will surely notice you kind reminder.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to link the posts. I don't mind cross-posting as long as they are linked.

Comment: Still I'll take care~Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by `awk`,

```
awk '{for(i=$2;i<$3;i++)print $1,i,$4}' file
```

Set the start and end of the range as $2 and $3, respectively.
And Print as request for the range in each line.

Comment: awk '{B=int($2);E=int($3);for(i=B;i<E;++i) printf("%s\t%d\t%s\n",$1,i,$4);}' in.bed

Comment: Thanks!!! That is Pierre Lindenbaum's reply just now (I post this question other place since so helpless and can't found answer), I'm trying now, but my data is too large, haven't run out

Comment: Both be ran out. These two ways lead to same result, and exactly correct.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use set and map operations with `bedops`, `bedmap`, and `cut`:

```
$ bedops --chop 1 foo.bed | bedmap --faster --echo --echo-map-id --delim "\t" - foo.bed | cut -f1,2,4 > answer.txt
```

Might offer some flexibility if other types of divisions and signal mapping are needed.

Comment: Could you explain the role of the bedops and bedmap commands and the options you use ?